# No module named static

Tags: static, cherrypy

I have problem when I use "from spyre import server"

Issue:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyre/server.py", line 16, in 
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file
ImportError: No module named static

```
import matplotlib,jinja2
from spyre import server

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class SimpleSineApp(server.App):
    title = "Simple Sine App"
    inputs = [{ "input_type":"text","variable_name":"freq","value":5,"action_id":"sine_wave_plot"}]

    outputs = [{"output_type":"plot","output_id":"sine_wave_plot","on_page_load":True }]

    def getPlot(self, params):
        f = float(params['freq'])
        print f
        x = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,np.pi/150)
        y = np.sin(f*x)
        fig = plt.figure()
        splt1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        splt1.plot(x,y)
        return fig

app = SimpleSineApp()
app.launch()
```

How can I solve this issue?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the following works for me. Of course this way you need all the *-dev* dependencies to build `pandas` and `matplotlib`.

```
virtualenv test
. test/bin/activate
pip install dataspyre
python spyredemo.py
```

I guess your exception is a dependency issue. If you installed `cherrypy` from OS package repo you may have old version. Type in terminal `pip freeze | grep cherrypy` and make sure it's at least >= 3.2. To test it open Python interactive console and type:

```
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file
```

If it doesn't work you need to upgrade CherryPy. You may need to remove the OS package before.

```
pip install -U cherrypy
```